# Create both static and shared library with GNU libtool?

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, autotools, libtool

I am using the GNU autotools (including automake!) for my project. I would like to know if I could create a static and a shared library using libtool? Or would the declarations be separate? Would this:

```
LT_INIT(shared static)
```

work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing besides `LT_INIT` is needed, it defaults to building both static and shared libraries. If you like, you can again explicitly state the defaults (but it is sort of redundant)

```
LT_INIT
AC_ENABLE_SHARED
AC_ENABLE_STATIC
```

edit: manual says `LT_INIT([shared])` and `LT_INIT([static])` (combined to `LT_INIT([shared static])` shall also work. Also manual's more precise wording on what's default when `LT_INIT` is given:
*this macro turns on shared libraries if they are
     available, and also enables static libraries if they don't
     conflict with the shared libraries.*

Comment: So when ./configure && make is run, a static AND shared library is automatically produced?

Comment: Unless configure.ac sports a, say, `AC_DISABLE_STATIC`, it will build both by default. `AC_DISABLE_STATIC` may be countered by using `./configure --enable-static` for example. So what's in `configure.ac` really is a developer's suggestion to its users.